# Count advanced in SQL Server group by 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, multiple-columns

I have 1 table like the picture

[image]

I want to count column number the output as follows

[image]

I try but it not show column ID and name as I want.

```
select id, name, number, count(number)
from table_demo
group by id, name, number
```

My result

[image]

Can't help you with the SQL Server 2019

Comment: The query is doing exactly what you asked it to do. ID #1, name A, has exactly one row, which is what your query says. The same is true of ID #2, name B, and ID #3, name C, and every other row. If you want the count of the numbers in the Number column, then remove ID, name and number from your SELCT list and use `SELECT Count(number) as numbercounts` instead. You can't show the other columns in your GROUP BY, because that changes what it does and makes it do exactly as you're saying it does.

Comment: in excel have function countif,  so i want count sql server same same function countif excel

Comment: SQL Server is not Excel. It follows the SQL guidelines. You should find a good SQL book so you learn the basics - it will save you a lot of frustration going forward.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Remove `id, name` from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` of your query you will get the required `count` value. After that do a `INNER JOIN` back to your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```sql
select id, name, number, count(*) over (partition by number)
from table_demo order by 1,2
```

For future reading [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [SQL Count Function with Partition By Clause](https://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.asp)

Comment: The result was exactly, tks for your help